# Can we fetch ga:users and ga:newusers in single fetch?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

looking at the metrics and Dimension explorer ga:users and ga:newusers look like it can be fetched together but when i select the "Only show fields that are allowed in segments" then ga:users could not be seen does that mean ga:users and ga:newusers cannot be fetched together?

[with selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UKOj.png)

[without selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUmYq.png)

I tried fetching them both together and also ga:source,ga:medium when i verified the numbers with data from UA website the ga:newuser number matches but ga:user number have huge difference

Comment: I am using adverity to fetch ga-ua data

Comment: I'm surprised that is still works